# What's the best way to work with the Facebook .Net Sdk

Tags: .net, facebook-sdk-4.0, code-structure

For this Question i use the example of a .Net web application with the MVC design pattern.

Lets say i want to add the facebook feed of a public page to my site.
Now, as far as i know, there is two ways.

Either use the JavaScript API and let the client do the requests to the FB API or to use the Facebook .Net SDK.

I decide to use the Facebook .Net SDK, receive the data on a page request and render it on the page.

**My first Question** would be, could this become a performance issue? And since the FB API call is asyncronous, i suppose i would have use something like SignalR to send it to the client so that the normal site request doesn't wait for the async call to finish.

**My second Question** is, would i have to create a new FacebookClient on every request or is there a way to implement something like that more globally in my application? So that not every request on my site results in a new FacebookClient to be created.

Comment: You do not *implement* the SDK, you use it I guess?

Comment: Yeah true. My mistake.